# Insert document OR update if it matches the filter

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use initializeOrderedBulkOp in NodeJS MongoDB in the following scenario:

If the document exists, update some fields. If the document doesn't exist, insert the full document. Both objects are available

```
const bulk = this.collection<T>().initializeOrderedBulkOp();
const op = {
  insert: {
    docId: 'xxxx',
    data: { name: 'Elon', location: 'US' }
  },
  update: {
    'data.location': 'South Africa'
  },
  filter: {
    docId: 'xxxx'
  }
};
const bulk = this.collection<T>().initializeOrderedBulkOp(options);
bulk.find(op.filter).upsert().updateOne({
  $setOnInsert: op.insert,
  $set: op.update
});
```

And I get this error

```
MongoBulkWriteError: Updating the path 'data.name' would create a conflict at 'data'
```

The documentation says that `$setOnInsert` is ignored if the filter matches but I still get this error

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to update 'data.location' in both cases but with different values. Is this your intention?

Comment: Yes. The full document is different than what I need to update, as most data integrations are. The idea was to insert OR update, not both

Comment: In most cases when you want to upsert the location value of a document, you want it to be the same if you update it or created it. It is normal to add other fields in each case, but if the same key is being updated, it is common to use the same value for both cases. I understand that you want to update the name only in the case of insert. It is less common to give different values to the same field - `location` in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different **values** (to the same keys) if you update or create, you can use an aggregation pipeline with a `$merge` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$facet: {
      newDocs: [
        {$match: {docId: {$nin: [1, 2, 4, 5]}}},
        {$limit: 1}
      ],
      existingDocs: [
        {$match: {docId: {$in: [1, 2, 4, 5]}}},
        {$addFields: {
            newLoc: [
              {docId: 1, location: "South Africa"},
              {docId: 4, location: "Italy"},
              {docId: 2, location: "Nepal"},
              {docId: 5, location: "Jordan"}
            ]
          }
        },
        {$set: {
            newLoc: {
              $first: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$newLoc",
                  cond: {$eq: ["$$this.docId", "$docId"]}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {$set: {
            "data.location": "$newLoc.location",
            newLoc: "$$REMOVE"
        }}
      ]
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      res: {$concatArrays: ["$existingDocs", "$newDocs"]},
      existingIds: "$existingDocs.docId",
      newDocs: [
        {
          docId: 1,
          data: {
            name: "Elton",
            location: "US"
          }
        },
        {
          docId: 2,
          data: {
            name: "Kyle",
            location: "England"
          }
        },
        {
          docId: 4,
          data: {
            name: "Elon",
            location: "US"
          }
        },
        {
          docId: 5,
          data: {
            name: "Dan",
            location: "France"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      res: {$concatArrays: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$newDocs",
              cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$this.docId", "$existingIds"]}}
            }
          },
          "$res"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$res"},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GccXRQZ_-MB)